# Special characters not appearing in PDF

Tags: r, pdf

I am creating a plot that plots text, some of which contains special characters. When I make this plot within RStudio it seems fine, and when I export to JPEG it is fine. However, when I export to PDF some characters are not printed correctly. Is there a way to encode the file appropriately so the correct characters are displayed?

here is a small example to show the issue:

This is fine:

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n")
text(1, 1, "bʱaːu")
```

This is not fine:

```
pdf('test.pdf')
plot(1, 1, type = "n")
text(1, 1, "bʱaːu")
dev.off()
```

Comment: I have tried using `cairo_pdf()` from the Cairo package, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `grDevices::cairo_pdf` instead.

```
grDevices::cairo_pdf("example.pdf")
plot(1, 1, type = "n")
text(1, 1, "bʱaːu")
dev.off()
```

***Result***

[image]

BTW, `text(1, 1, paste0("b", sprintf("\U02B1"), "aːu"))` would give you an unicode representation of `ʱ`.

Comment: So, is your solution to replace all special characters with unicode representations? The first code block you suggest doesn't work OOTB for me.

Comment: @SamPassmore As you can see, it works for me. Maybe you want to try the code again in a fresh R session.

Comment: In `ggplot2`, use `ggsave(p, filename = "example.pdf", device = cairo_pdf,
       width = 4, height = 3, units = "in")` . see https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2017/09/27/working-with-r-cairo-graphics-custom-fonts-and-ggplot/